# Automatic align paragraph

Tags: html, css

I know something from HTML and CSS, but i was coding themes for PHP-Fusion v7, so i didnt need this stuff around padding of paragraph (i dont know how to say it in english, im sorry). But im coding simple HTML and CSS portfolio for myself, but im stucked at this problem.

My problem is  `here`[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfc30ny9/)
And i want to make it to looks like this: [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/4oxhhn)

Can someone help me please with this? I dont know everything, but im learning fast and i dont know what to put in google to find my problem, so i cannot find it here too :/

Thank you ! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert all of your li elements to ul, see this:

```
<ul class="column-center">
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industrytypesetting industrtypesetting industr</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </li>
  <li>text of the printing and</li>
  <li>typesetting industr</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<li>` elements should be contained inside a  element. Try creating a structure like:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```